# Separate Command/Query DbContext in EFCore throw There is already an open DataReader

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception, datareader

We used Entity Framework Core 2.1 and Castle Windsor Interceptor With UoW pattern for managing transactions in my own project,in our project we separate command & query dbcontext in query context we ignored interceptor of transaction for that and on command dbcontext we register interceptor,in business service layer we register transaction interceptor on business service and inject both of context for handling business logic but sometime  on query context throw Exception :

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which
>   must be closed first.

we can't be allowing MARS in our connection string.how can we fix this problem.

thanks.

Comment: Without the code it's impossible to help. That error though means you tried to use the same context/connection for two different operations.

Comment: Btw Unit of Work has nothing to do with database transactions. It's **not** a transaction management pattern. You don't need a specific implementation if you use EF or NHibernate either - the ORM doesn't write anything to the database until `SaveChanges` is explicitly called. When it does, it performs all data manipulation inside an internal transaction